# Application be frozen when calling JS functions have alert()

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I am using Awesomium .NET 1.6.6.

When I use CallJavascriptFunction & ExecuteJavascriptWithResult in C#, the whole application will be frozen when there's alert() inside the invoked JS function. The JS code is simply like this:

```
function Helloworld()
{
alert("");
}
```

How to prevent this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "frozen" ? It just doesn't work anymore or is it frozen while the alert is up and then it continues?

Comment: Alert blocks until `OK` is clicked on the popped alert dialog... don't call alert.

Comment: Never use alerts if you use awesomium. Try to send them into your application to display errors/infos etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know your situation 100% it sounds like the problem is that alert() is a blocking call.

The solution: use a DOM based message box.

For example:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/panel/panel-form-example.html

or

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Alert blocking your script until OK is clicked **is a normal behavior**, alert is named that way for a reason.

If you want to create a message for the user, just write it nicely in your page.

Based on your function name I'd say you are just testing for now, you should try using `console.log("Hello world!")` with a **browser that has a console** :

- Firebug for Firefox. http://getfirebug.com/
- Chrome/Safari console.
- Opera Dragonfly.
- IE9 F12 key.